# Share contents to Windows 8 People app

Tags: c#, windows, windows-8

How to share contents to Peoples app from my app using Windows 8 share charm.
I got only Metro Tweet, Wikipedia and Email app in the share charm, how to include People app?
[image]

Comment: The apps you see in share charm depends upon what are you sharing. Suppose people app support only text and you are trying to share `StorageFile` file then it won't be displayed in share charm. So please specify what are you sharing.

Comment: What is the data format that you are trying to share?

Comment: I want to share only string

Answer (score 1):

I tested with [MSDN Sample App](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Sharing-Content-Source-App-d9bffd84), I get to know that people app only accepts link and HTML content for sharing. So you have to change you string data in html runtime.

Better you understand the msdn sample.